# Text align right in TD tag

Tags: html, css

I have text and image in the td tag. The text is stay still but trying to  `text-align: right;` an image. So I used span class on the image. But image doesn't listen to command still next to the text, not going right corner.

```
<td>マンションを購入しようとした時に何から始めたら良いでしょうか 
    <span class="open-button-big">
       <img src="img/open-button-big.png" class="open-button-big-class">
    </span>
</td>
```

it's looking like [image: this]:

and this is the *CSS*

```
table {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: none;
}

table {
    border-top: solid 1px blue;
}

tr {
    border-top: solid 1px blue;
}

th {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

td {
    font-size: 14px;
}


.Question {
    width: 40px;
}

span {

    text-align: right !important;
}

.open-button-big-class {
    width: 70px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Try float:right on image.

Comment: try display:inline-b,lock along with text-align:right on span

Comment: nope, it doesn't work both of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since span is an inline elements and it wraps the image you should set it's display to block or use a div instead. To align the whole span to the right, use `float: right`

```css
table {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

table {
  border-top: solid 1px blue;
}

tr {
  border-top: solid 1px blue;
}


td {
  font-size: 14px;
}

span {
  float: right !important;
  display: block;
}

.open-button-big-class {
  width: 70px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>マンションを購入しようとした時に何から始めたら良いでしょうか
      <span class="open-button-big">
       <img src="https://www.reduceimages.com/img/share-icon.png" class="open-button-big-class">
    </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think this should be in the comment box.

Comment: Just edited it, thanks for letting me have another minute for more detailed answer

Comment: but when I make table display none; and block with the toggle it returns with same problem

Comment: The default table display is `table` not `block`. (`display: table;`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
span {
    float: right !important;
}
```

But I strongly recommand using this kind of css selector:

```
table td span {
    float: right !important;
}
```

Because if you select just `span`, all of `span`s will get this style, using specific selection in better for controlling over other `span`s